# Converting a data frame to a parameter list for rmarkdown

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

I’m trying to covert a data frame to a data frame with a list of parameters to send to a parameterized markdown report. I'm following [R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html) as my guide.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


master_list <- tibble(
  client   = rep(1:2, each = 3),
  product  = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 2),
  price    = abs(rnorm(6))*10,
  quantity = round(runif(6)*100)      
)

report_list <- master_list %>%
  nest(-client) %>%
  mutate(filename = paste0("Report for ", client, ".pdf"))

# paramaters for report
params <- report_list %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(params = as.list(.))

reports <- bind_cols(report_list, params)

# code to send to rmarkdown::render
reports %>% 
  select(output_file = filename, params) %>% 
   purrr::pwalk(rmarkdown::render, input = "./Rmd/subscriber-report.Rmd")
```

Edit: This does work, but I feel the process to build the reports data frame is clunky (plus I don’t really like that params has an extra list level to deparse in the rmd code).  Any ideas on how to streamline the building of the reports data frame?

Comment: @akrun edit the question to make it a bit more clear (hopefully)

Comment: You could create this in a single chain `master_list %>% mutate(filename = paste0("Report for ", client, ".pdf")) %>% nest(-client, -filename) %>% transmute(client, filename, params = map(data,  as.list))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks, that helps, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.  Although I think it will work for what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically what I'd like is after the nest command to take each row an make a list with it as an additional column.  Preserving the "data" data frame as a list element.  (hopefully that's makes sense).

Comment: Perhaps `master_list %>% mutate(filename = paste0("Report for ", client, ".pdf")) %>% group_by(client, filename) %>% nest %>% transmute(client, filename, params = map(data, as_tibble))`

Comment: This doesn't put client and filename into the params.  Kindo of need a combination of the two... but the more I think about it your first solution works for my purposes just fine.  Just a tad of book keeping on the rmd side since we want to report by row...